# jQuery is not defined $ is not defined $(...).scrollable is not a function

Tags: jquery

> Error: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined /js/jquery.tools.min.js
>
> Error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined /js/popup.js
>
> Error: TypeError: $(...).scrollable is not a function /js/carousel.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script> 
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"; type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/…; type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-timer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am getting these errors. Please, can somebody give me some advice?

Comment: have you added jquery.js?

Comment: Sounds like you need to include jquery into your page.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have jQuery referenced on your page.

EDIT:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-timer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: @user2323604 is before the load of the tools.min.js ?

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery to your header ABOVE every other file containing jQuery or it wont work

EDIT:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-timer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: my js list is abouve please check out

Answer (score 0):

You need to **load the jQuery library and the jQuery-UI BEFORE the other libraries** that need to use it. And only one version of jQuery and jQuery UI ! You can not mix two together different versions together.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

// then the rest
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery-timer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When you copy/paste code from here and there, stop for a moment and see it, what that stuff do ?

Comment: @user2323604 Use the browser tools to see what is not loading.